# MySQL query error 1064 (syntax error)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to make the following query work but it seems to contain an error that I can't find. The query in question is:

```sql
select 
      A.*, 
      SD.* 
   from 
      (
         ( select 
                 V71.Sollevamento_idAttrezzatura, 
                 V71.Num_id_ON,  
                 V71.Affidato_INAIL, 
                 V71.Esito_Verifica, 
                 V71.Prima_Verifica, 
                 V71.Sospensione, 
                 V71.Data_Verbale, 
                 V71.Scadenza, 
                 CO.Nome, 
                 CO.Cognome, 
                 CO.CF, 
                 V71.Costo, 
                 V71.Sconto as ScontoVerbale, 
                 V71.Maggiorazione as MaggiorazioneVerbale, 
                 V71.Indirizzo, 
                 V71.Comune, 
                 V71.Cap, 
                 V71.Provincia, 
                 V71.Regione 
              from 
                 Verbale_Art71 as V71 
                    join Collaboratore as CO 
                       on V71.Codice_Tecnico = CO.Codice_Collaboratore 
              where 
                     V71.Data_Verbale >= '2014-01-01' 
                 and V71.Data_Verbale <= '2014-12-31' ) as VC 
         join 
         ( select 
                 S.Natura, 
                 S.Anno_Immatricolazione, 
                 S.Codice_Attribuzione_Matricola, 
                 S.Provincia_Immatricolazione, 
                 S.Numero_Matricola, 
                 S.idSpecifica, 
                 S.N_Panieri_Idroestrattori, 
                 S.Modello, 
                 S.Numero_Fabbrica, 
                 S.Anno_Costruzione, 
                 S.Sconto as ScontoAttr, 
                 S.Maggiorazione as MaggiorazioneAttr, 
                 P71.Tipo_Attr, 
                 S.Sede, 
                 S.idAttrezzatura 
              from 
                 Sollevamento as S 
                    join Periodicita_Art71 as P71 
                       on S.idPeriodicita = P71.idPeriodicita ) as SP 
            on VC.Sollevamento_idAttrezzatura = SP.idAttrezzatura
      ) as A 
      join 
      ( select 
              D.Ragione_Sociale, 
              D.Indirizzo, 
              D.Cap, 
              D.Comune, 
              D.Provincia, 
              D.Regione, 
              D.CF as CF_Ditta, 
              D.P_IVA, 
              SC.idSede 
           from 
              Ditta as D 
                 join Sede as SC 
                    on SC.Ditta = D.idDitta ) as SD 
      on ATTR71.Sede = SD.idSede
```

MySQL notifies that the syntax error is near `as A join (select D.Ragione_Sociale, D.Indirizzo, D.Cap, D.Comune, D.Provincia`

Anyone can help me find it? I've been looking for it since early morning and I'm going nuts. Thank anyone that will help me in advance, Giacomo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a select clause

```
select A.*, SD.* 
from 
    (/* You are missing a select * from here */
        (
            select ..
        ) as VC
        join
```

Try with

```
select A.*, SD.* 
from 
    (select * from
        (
            select V71.Sollevamento_idAttrezzatura, V71.Num_id_ON,  V71.Affidato_INAIL, V71.Esito_Verifica, V71.Prima_Verifica, V71.Sospensione, V71.Data_Verbale, V71.Scadenza, CO.Nome, CO.Cognome, CO.CF, V71.Costo, V71.Sconto as ScontoVerbale, V71.Maggiorazione as MaggiorazioneVerbale, V71.Indirizzo, V71.Comune, V71.Cap, V71.Provincia, V71.Regione 
            from Verbale_Art71 as V71 
            join 
            Collaboratore as CO 
                on V71.Codice_Tecnico = CO.Codice_Collaboratore 
            where V71.Data_Verbale >= '2014-01-01' and V71.Data_Verbale <= '2014-12-31'
        ) as VC 
        join 
        (
            select S.Natura, S.Anno_Immatricolazione, S.Codice_Attribuzione_Matricola, S.Provincia_Immatricolazione, S.Numero_Matricola, S.idSpecifica, S.N_Panieri_Idroestrattori, S.Modello, S.Numero_Fabbrica, S.Anno_Costruzione, S.Sconto as ScontoAttr, S.Maggiorazione as MaggiorazioneAttr, P71.Tipo_Attr, S.Sede, S.idAttrezzatura 
            from Sollevamento as S 
            join 
            Periodicita_Art71 as P71 
                on S.idPeriodicita = P71.idPeriodicita
        ) as SP 
        on VC.Sollevamento_idAttrezzatura = SP.idAttrezzatura
    ) as A 
    join 
    (
        select D.Ragione_Sociale, D.Indirizzo, D.Cap, D.Comune, D.Provincia, D.Regione, D.CF as CF_Ditta, D.P_IVA, SC.idSede 
        from Ditta as D 
        join Sede as SC 
            on SC.Ditta = D.idDitta
    ) as SD 
        on ATTR71.Sede = SD.idSede
```

Answer (score 0):

Your final alias

```
 on ATTR71.Sede = SD.idSede
```

should be

```
 on A.Sede = SD.idSede
```

You can see it easily once the formatting / readability is better.  The "A" was the alias result of the first JOINs using the ATTR71 alias table... The last join was only to the "A" alias and not the ATTR71 table.

Comment: I also noticed that, but that would not throw a syntax error, this is not the problem here. The alias is not in the query OP provided probably because this query is a subquery of a bigger one .. See my answer for correct fix.